# how to execute update query from one form to another

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-access-2007

im working on one application where in first form data is putting into datagridview , in 2nd form having one password textbox if user enter details in 1st form then quickly 2nd form should called after entering his valid password then only 1st form data should enter else pop up should display invalid user , i done coding for that but whenever i execute code on 1st form password textbox is display but on 1st forms message.box also display with that ("Record update successfully") i want after valid entry into textbox then after form 1st pop up should display here is my code of form 1

```
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = null;
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;



            string medicinename = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Medicine_Name"].Value.ToString();
          string quantity = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString();


            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to insert data", "Data insert Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Medicine_Available_Detail set [Availability]=[Availability]-@Quantity where [Medicine_Name]=@Medicine_Name", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quantity);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medicine_Name", medicinename);
                Form1 frm = new Form1();
                frm.Show();
                con.Open();
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
                userlist();


                try
                {
                    string query = "select Medicine_Name,Availability from Medicine_Available_Detail where Medicine_Name='" + medicinename+ "'";

                    using (cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                string Medicine_Name = (string)reader["Medicine_Name"];
                                int Availability = (int)reader["Availability"];

                                MessageBox.Show("Total stock of: " + medicinename + " is now: " + Availability + " ");


                            }

                            reader.Close();

                        }

                        con.Close();

                    }

                    dataGridView1.Refresh();


                }
```

form 2 code:

```
private void txtinput_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                this.txtinput.MaxLength = 4;
                cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Login set [Sales_count]=[Sales_count]+1 where [Unique_No]=@Unique_No and To_Date='" + DateTime.Now + "'", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique_No", txtinput.Text);
                con.Open();
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (n < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No. pls try again later");

                }

                con.Close();
            }
```

image i will show you what is output coming rightnow(which is i dont want)

[image]

Comment: If you need a dialog then you should call Form.ShowDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the 2nd form close whether your input is good or bad? If so then change

Form2:

```
if (n == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No. pls try again later");
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
else
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Form1:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Medicine_Available_Detail set [Availability]=[Availability]-@Quantity where [Medicine_Name]=@Medicine_Name", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quantity);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medicine_Name", medicinename);
Form1 frm = new Form1(); // Should this really be Form1 and not Form2?
DialogResult dr = frm.ShowDialog();
if(dr != DialogResult.OK)
{
    return; // Do not proceed if dr result is not successful
}
con.Open();
int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
userlist();
```

Comment: Hi friend i done this but its still not working here is code which is you given but still its not done

Comment: @Atul change `if (n < 0)` to `if (n == 0)`. I think `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will never return a negative integer only 0 to positive n numbers.

Comment: i done that but debugger went to this statement only and showing popup if (n == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No. pls try again later");
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}

Comment: Take a look on [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx). If the return is 0 it means there are no rows affected by your query. Then this means the issue is within your update statement. No way for us to verify. Do check if the generated query is valid by executing it directly on the database. Possible  issue is with your `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` try using `cmd.Parameters.Add` instead and specify the proper SqlDbType.

Comment: now i written code on button click event but evry time debugger go into   if (n==0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No. pls try again later");
                    //this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                } 

this code either i written valid unique_no or not

here is im pasting my whole code is there any issue into update query??? i updated answer